# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined angular7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-services, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I have a component employee 
I am trying to create a form, for which I have created "employee component", "employee service" and "employee model"

In employee.component.html I have below form

```
 <form #employeeform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeform)">
          <input type="hidden" name="_id"  [(ngModel)]="employeeservice.selectedEmployee._id" #_id="ngModel"/>
        </form>
```

In employee.component.ts I have below code

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';

 @Component({
    selector: 'app-employee',
    templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
    providers : [EmployeeService]
 });

 export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private employeeservice : EmployeeService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
   }
```

This is my employee.service.ts file which I have imported in employee component

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { Employee } from './employee.model';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class EmployeeService {
   selectedEmployee : Employee;
   employees: Employee[];

   constructor() { }
 }
```

Here is my employee.model.ts which I have imported in employee service

```
 export class Employee {
     _id: string;
     name: string;
     position : string;
     office : string;
     salary : number;
 }
```

I am getting the below error in my browser console when I run the command "ng serve"

```
 EmployeeComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EmployeeComponent.html:9)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
```

Am I missing any imports that a form needs or what could be the error. I am a beginner and trying to learn angular. I have googled for the solution, but I couldn't find any relevant solution. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as the error says: you want to access the _id but the `selectedEmployee` is never actually defined.

You can either only display the element when it has been defined using `*ngIf` on your html element or give it a default value like so `selectedEmployee : Employee = {}` (setting any variable needed from the class accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to create an instance of the employee inside of the EmployeeComponent , and every time when you open the component - retrieve it from the service and target it at the html code. Something like:

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    employee: Employee;

    constructor(private employeeservice : EmployeeService) { 
      this.employee = employeeservice.getSelectedEmployee();
    }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
   }
```

and later at the html:

```
 <form #employeeform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeform)">
          <input type="hidden" name="_id"  [(ngModel)]="employee._id" #_id="ngModel"/>
        </form>
```

Or pass it again with Injection.
At the moment, the problem is that your EmployeeComponent can't target like you want (passing from html to the service variable), so you are getting - *Undefined* error.

Comment: I  have done the below changes export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  public employee;
  constructor(private employeeservice : EmployeeService) {
    this.employee = employeeservice.selectedEmployee;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

} still I am getting the same error

Comment: But inside of your service ( export class EmployeeService ), do you have data inputs ? If no - you need to create also the Employee in the constructor (like other people suggest) . But usually in the service - you retrieve the data from somewhere (REST call or whatever..)

Answer (score 0):

Initially, when the component is loaded, the `employee.service` has no value set for `selectedEmployee`. The html is rendered and the `[(ngModel)]="employeeservice.selectedEmployee._id"` expects a value of `employeeservice.selectedEmployee._id`. But `employeeservice.selectedEmployee` is not initialized yet, hence the error.

I would suggest you to use a default _id in case you haven't set the `employeeservice.selectedEmployee._id`.

For that use `[(ngModel)]="employeeservice.selectedEmployee ?  employeeservice.selectedEmployee._id : 0"`

Answer (score 0):

**Your employee.service.ts file should be like this.**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { Employee } from './employee.model';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class EmployeeService {
     selectedEmployee: Employee = {    
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    position: '',
    office: '',
    salary: null
  };
   employees: Employee[];

   constructor() { }
 }
```